# How to use .net6 to operate redis？

Tags: asp.net-core, redis

I upgraded to the latest .net6 version, but how to configure the connection service, I can't find the entry. Can I still use the previous Startup.cs configuration in .net6? Any help is greatly appreciated!I have read the documentation, but it didn't help me：https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/6.0

Comment: You can keep startup.cs in your .net 6 project, I have add a link in the comment under my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1. You can register redis service like below.

```
builder.Services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
{
    options.Configuration = "jason******FebB5A=,ssl=True,abortConnect=False";
});
```

[image]

#### And you can use redis in your controller, like below:

```
public HomeController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, CosmosClient client,IDistributedCache distributedCache)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _client = client;
    _distributedCache = distributedCache;
}
```

[image]

#### And the test result like below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but can I still use the startup.cs file to configure in .net6?

Comment: @AbuSadatBhuiyaDipu I’m not sure,I haven’t try it. As official doc said remove startup.cs is a update,don’t need it anymore.

Comment: @AbuSadatBhuiyaDipu I will try it tomorrow, i will update answer later. If you think my solution is useful to you,could you accept it as answer,thank you.

Comment: @AbuSadatBhuiyaDipu https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/0e0372c3c1d895c3ce195ba983b1e03d#i-like-the-startup-class-can-i-keep-it